# Squarefree numbers with an odd number of primefactors vs Squarefree numbers with an even number of primefactors

Tags: number-theory

Consider all the squarefree numbers from $2N+1$ to $N^2$.

Now arrange these squarefree numbers in $2$ groups :

1. Squarefree numbers with an odd numbers of prime factors. For instance the primes from $2N+1$ to $N^2$.
2. Squarefree numbers with an even numbers of prime factors. For instance the semiprimes from $2N+1$ to $N^2$.

Now we define $n(O(N))$ as the *number* of squarefree numbers between $2N+1$ and $N^2$ which have an odd number of prime factors.

Likewise we define $n(E(N))$ as the *number* of squarefree numbers between $2N+1$ and $N^2$ which have an even number of prime factors.

Now $n(O(N))+n(E(N))$ is approximately equal to $(1-(1/2^2+1/3^2+1/5^2...+1/p^2))*(N^2-(2N+1))$

where $p$ is the largest prime less than or equal to $N$.

But what about $n(O(N))-n(E(N))$ ?

My hope is that this inequality is always true :

$n(O(N))-n(E(N))<N$

Edit:
I am afraid this problem is not easy to solve.

I found this on wikipedia, which is somewhat related to the problem. :

The number ${\pi _k}(n)$
of positive integers less than or equal to n with exactly $k$ prime divisors (not necessarily distinct) is asymptotic to:

$${\pi _k}(n) \approx \left( {{n \over {\log n}}} \right){{{{(\log \log n)}^{k - 1}}} \over {(k - 1)!}}$$

But this is an asymptotic result. I do not think general upper bounds and lower bounds on the number of $k$-almost primes are known.

Comment: Writing things like $N(O(N))$ which appear to use the letter $N$ in two radically different ways is confusing.  To your question:  how far have you searched?

Comment: You are right. I have corrected this. I have searched  up until $7^2$.

Comment: That's not very far.  There's only one number, $2\times 3\times 5$ that has three distinct prime factors in that range, and none have four.

Comment: The LHS of your inequality is the negation of the [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function), but restricted instead to $2N+1 \cdots N^2$. For large $N$, the restriction is basically equivalent since $N^2 \ggg 2N+1$. It is known that $\lvert M(N^2) \rvert < N$ is [untrue for *some* value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_conjecture) below $10^{10^{40}}$. Unsurprisingly, no counterexample is known, and possibly never will be as that bound is much larger than the number of bits in the universe.